# pip says modules "weren't found" to uninstall, but pip list shows them

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, package-managers, canopy

With `pip list` I'm shown a listing of the installed modules, which includes scipy, numpy, and pandas.

If I `pip install -U...` any of those, it checks it, sees its up-to-date, and returns to prompt.  But if I `pip uninstall pandas` or any of the items I can see in the list, it says

`Can't uninstall numpy. No files were found to uninstall`

I installed everything that has to do with Python through Enthought's Canopy Stack.

Comment: Does `pip freeze` list those packages?

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, but with `mod == ver` where `pip list` showed `mod(ver)`

Comment: @BrenBarn is this because my modules are located in `\users\Jeffrey\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages`?

Comment: I don't use Canopy so I'm afraid I can't be of much more help.  It sounds like there is some sort of mixup in pip's understanding of what it has installed, possibly interacting with stuff that Canopy may have installed itself, but that's about all I can discern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is some extra care required when installing/package managing with Canopy - for example, devs/staff @ Enthought say (eg https://support.enthought.com/entries/22914233-Using-non-EPD-package-installers-such-as-pip)

"The best practice, when you wish to install an EPD package from another source, is first to uninstall it (`enpkg --remove some_package`), then to install it using whatever technique you prefer" such as (`pip install some_package`)

It's worth noting that the 'sklearn' module is letting me `import datasets` after having used the Canopy Package Manager to update (33) out-of-date packages.  ***NOTE: THESE WERE PACKAGES PIP SAID WERE UP-TO-DATE!***

To sum up: if you installed Canopy, use the package manager (IMHO, always, even though there is some work-around listed in the link above) to keep updated and then work from the prompt if you choose.  ***FOR SOME REASON PIP CANNOT SEE (?) THE PACKAGES BEING MANAGED BY CANOPY!!!***